# Angular 2: Array with checkbox not working properly

Tags: arrays, angular, checkbox, angular2-ngmodel

I'm binding one array with Checkbox. However, When I try to change bool attribute for single element of array but it changes for all elements.

My HTML Component is as below.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let karyalay of karyalayListFinal">
  <div class="checkbox-fade fade-in-primary">
    <label>
      <input formControlName="karyalay_group" type="checkbox" name="karyalaysCheckbox" value="{{karyalay.karyalayId}}" [(ngModel)]="karyalay.isChecked" 
      (click)="callEvents(karyalay.karyalayId)">
      <span>{{karyalay.karyalayName}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to change value of single or selected element as below.

```
for (let karyalay of this.karyalayListFinal) {
    let tempInd = _.findIndex(this.roleMasterEventList, {'KARYALAY_ID': karyalay.karyalayId});
    if (tempInd > -1) {
      this.karyalayListFinal[tempInd].isChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Actually, if tempInd > -1 then and then only that element's value should be changed. But it changes for all.

Don't know whether this is ngModel issue or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting input tag inside *ngFor will create multiple input tags. And name property for input must be different for all. As HTML configure changes for input property using the name property. So, make this name property unique for every input by keeping a name field in the model passed in *ngFor. 
And target the checked property instead of ngModel. And do something like
**[checked]="yourmodel.isChecked"**, keep default value of isChecked property in your model as false.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: I did same and I posted my answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it seems that your approach is too complicated.

I don't know when you call this for each-loop, but I suppose that you already know or have the id you are searching for at this point. Let's call it `searchID`.

If you want to find the object with the matching id simply use the for each loop as follows:

```
this.karyalayListFinal.forEach( el =>  {
   if(el.karyalayId === searchID) {
      el.isChecked = true;
   }         
});
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried your solution also, but the result is same. And it also throws  'Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.' Error

Comment: Okay. So, when do you exactly call this code? In the constructor? In onInit()?

Answer (score 0):

you are running this loop for all the elements in "this.karyalayListFinal"

```
for (let karyalay of this.karyalayListFinal) {
    let tempInd = _.findIndex(this.roleMasterEventList, {'KARYALAY_ID': karyalay.karyalayId});
    if (tempInd > -1) {
      this.karyalayListFinal[tempInd].isChecked = true;
    }
}
```

might be possible that the condition "*tempInd > -1*" is satisfied for all the elements in "this.karyalayListFinal" and hence all are changing.

Answer (score 0):

I used `[checked]="karyalay.isChecked"` instead of ngModel in the HTML Code and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

"name" attribute written in input field must be unique for every element created by the loop
you must bind the id of every object coming in an array "karyalayListFinal" to make them unique.